# Displaying Tabview instead of Menu in Menubar App

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am new to OSX App development and finds things a little different from that of iOS. I am trying to create a sample Menubar App. I can display a menu using the command

[statusItem setMenu: startMenu];

But i dont know how can i display a TabView instead of menu. Can some body help me with this.

where statusMenu is an outlet of NSMenu and statusitem is an object of NSStatusItem

Comment: Please don't (ab)use unrelated tags.

Comment: Updated my answer, make sure to check it out.

Comment: Is a "menubar app" a status item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant. You have to display it in a window, which you can open on the click of the status item.
You can make the window borderless.

---

### 1.

You can either use this one here, which is a NSTableView in a window, which can fake the layout of a `NSMenu`:

[JGMenuWindow](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/mac-os-x/controls/jgmenuwindow)

Though I would not recommend that, because if Mac OS X has some layout changes, this will stay the same.

---

### 2.

Or you can use a normal window, which you customise, like here:

[Popup](https://github.com/shpakovski/Popup)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the custom view of a NSMenuItem, so you could just try adding your tableview to the NSMenuItem of choice.